# Snowflake chooses timestamp format over date format on load of CSV

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a `CSV` with a column containing basic dates (like 01/11/2020).

I have specified in the `FILELOADER` the following format specifications:

- `DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY'`
- `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY  HH24:MI'`.

This should create a match for the date columns using the `DATE_FORMAT`.  However, `Snowflake` sees the date column and identifies it as a timestamp column.  Since no time exists in that column it fails to match the `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` and the load fails.

Why is `Snowflake` choosing to identify my date column as a timestamp column?

Here is the full FILE FORMAT specification I am using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT jobstats_csv_format
  TYPE = CSV FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' SKIP_HEADER = 1 NULL_IF = ('NULL', 'null') EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = true COMPRESSION = AUTO FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY='"' DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY' TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY  HH24:MI';
```

... this file format specification is referred to in my stage definition ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE tct_jobstats_input_stage
  URL='azure://blahblahblah.blob.core.windows.net/tct-filefly-input/'
  CREDENTIALS=(AZURE_SAS_TOKEN='blahblahblahblahblah')
  FILE_FORMAT = jobstats_csv_format;
```

... and the code I am using to load it...

```
    try 
    {
        var load_cmd  = "COPY INTO LifelineRemoved ";
            load_cmd += "FROM @tct_jobstats_input_stage ";
            load_cmd += "PATTERN='.*Lifeline Removed During Date Range.*[.]csv.*';";
        var load_stmt = snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: load_cmd } );
        load_stmt.execute();
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
        result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
        result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt; 
    }
```

... and here is a (header + single) line of data from the CSV which fails to load.
    account,customerstatus,certifieddate,lifelineremoveddate,lifelineremovedreason,telephonenumber1,linestatus,activationdate,disconnectdate,firstname,lastname,serviceaddress1,serviceaddress2,servicecity,servicestate,servicezip,Column1
    123456,Active,11/26/2019,12/1/2019,DSN D Denied 90-5 The customer has had their LifeL,(321) 5551212,Active,11/26/2019,,JOHN,DOE,1524 EXAMPLE ST,,FRESNO,CA,93706,

... and finally the error I am seeing...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

TIMESTAMP_FORMAT is a preview feature at this time, so it may not be ready for production use.  As a workaround, you can use the `COPY INTO mytable FROM (SELECT FROM ... )` pattern to apply custom transformations on each field.  Or load as text and convert after.  Lastly it always helps if you can provide the code and sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I tried loading sample data with your specification and it worked well with WebUI.

This is how my sample data looks

[image]

```
01/09/2020,01/09/2020 23:59,9th Jan
01/10/2020,01/10/2020 22:58,10th Jan
01/11/2020,01/11/2020 21:57,11th Jan
01/12/2020,01/12/2020 20:56,12th Jan
```

Create the following file format and defined Date/TS formats

[image]

And when you load the data from WebUI, it works perfectly.

[image]

With the correct file, the format defines the data type also looks perfect.

[image]

If the file format definition is incorrect for date and timestamp, you will get the following error

[image]

Comment: I tried creating a new File Format using the WebUI selections you made above.  Unfortunately, with my sample data I still have the same problem.  I will now upload better example data and the selections I have made for file format configuration.

Comment: Why don't you use the option (FILEFORMAT => MY_FILE_FORMAT) with your SQL command? I did not see the file format option with your command

Comment: Hmm.  I think it's because in my command I am referring to the stage, and in the stage definition, I have the file format specified.  I'll update.

Comment: I can't seem to isolate the difference between the data which triggers Snowflake to mis-identify the dates in this file as timestamps (it fails on all rows).  I guess I was hoping you might have some insight into the code.

Comment: Perhaps your suggestion of applying a transform in the query, to reformat the date to use (perhaps) dashes might trigger things to work correctly.  It's a workaround, and that will suffice for now.  But perhaps a bug report needs to be submitted for this.

Comment: ARGH!!!!  I just figured it out.  Somehow that column in the table definition was defined as TIMEZONE_LTZ instead of DATE.  This is an oversight on my part.  Sorry for the wild goose chase.  We can close this.

Answer (score 0):

Checked the table definition to ensure column type matches expected data.  In my case, I had a Timezone_LTZ column type for a column which should have been a DATE.

Answer (score 0):

It took me ages to figure out the date upload into Snowflake from a Pandas DF. For me the solution was to set the correct ISO 8601 format. As seen in the link, you can set it as below:

```
dataDF["DATE_COL"] = dataDF["DATE_COL"].astype('datetime64')
dataDF["DATE_COL"] = dataDF["DATE_COL"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #Note full format can be strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

[My Solution for Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76904688/1017607)